# Website visitor location in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, geolocation, location, ip

My ASP.NET website needs to know the city and country of the visiting user. I have tried following code:

```
string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();
```

And then making a web request to `http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=ip`

This method returns me correct user location in some cases, but when user's ISP has hosted server in other country or city, then instead of giving me user's current city (from where he is browsing the website) it gives me the server hosted location.

How can I get the user's location regardless of where his ISP has hosted the server? Like Google does in Google Maps (where browser asks for permission to share location). Or any other better way?

Comment: What you are looking for is called [Geolocation](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html).

Comment: I think you already gotten the answer that HTML5 geolocation will give you a more accurate position. However, the problem is it needs the user to explicitly share you the location. Check this for information: http://www.ipgeo5.com

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problems

[See msdn code sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETIPtoLocation-2f03490c/sourcecode?fileId=22563&pathId=1250756808)

Comment: This is not the answer to my problem. The code sample link you have given gives the location of the IP, and that's what I was doing (check my code sample). I think what RGraham has said, "Geolocation", is the answer.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about Google Maps. It is using the IP address to reverse lookup your location. If the IP address is hosted by an ISP outside your city/country, you are just out of luck.